# How to create intent to open an FTP link in a browser

Tags: java, android

I have created an intent that open HTTP links in the browser.this is the basic intent for it

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(LinkUrl.get(position)));

// sending data to new activity
startActivity(intent);
```

The problem I am facing is if the LinkUrl arraylist has an FTP link (for example ftp://10.3.3.115), my app force closes and is not able to open it in the browser.

What can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: well my college's internet network has an ftp link which i'm able to open from browser and access it..the thing is i dont want to ignore it but rather open it with the browser

Comment: What does the logcat say when the app force closes?

Comment: this is what is says  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Comment: So you can catch this exception so your app does not crash.